# Is there a way to change the name of started Thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

Is there a way to change the name of a started `Thread` or `Thread.setName(String name)` is only available in Thread initialization block?

Comment: What happened when you tried it? What happened when you read the Javadoc?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set it in any part of your code that still has a reference to the original Thread, and as long as the SecurityManager allows it.

Answer (score 8):

The function is called setName(String name);

```
Thread t = new Thread(...);
t.start();
t.setName("...");
```

Answer (score 0):

The Thread name can be set when instantiating the Thread object *and also after the fact* using `Thread.currentThread().setName`

```
public class NamedThreadExample implements Runnable {

  public static final String THREAD_NAME_GOES_HERE = "Original Name";
  public static final String NEW_THREAD_NAME_GOES_HERE = "New Name";

  public void run() {
    System.out.println("I am a Thread and my name is " 
                        + Thread.currentThread().getName());

    Thread.currentThread().setName(NEW_THREAD_NAME_GOES_HERE);

    System.out.println("I am a Thread and my name is " 
                        + Thread.currentThread().getName());
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    (new Thread(new NamedThreadExample(), THREAD_NAME_GOES_HERE)).start();
  }
}
```

Producing the output

```
I am a Thread and my name is Original Name
I am a Thread and my name is New Name
```

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#Thread%28java.lang.Runnable,%20java.lang.String%29

Comment: How does this answer relate to changing the thread name AFTER it has been started?